# Iterating through table and get the value of a button in each tablerow jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have buttons in a table which are created dynamically. I want to iterate through a table, get the tablerows which contain a checked checkbox and get the value of a button inside the tablerow. I want to push the values in an array after. The buttons don't have a unique ID so I cannot get their values by id.
I tried to get the values through giving the buttons a class and itering works fine but the array is filled with empty entries.

```
$("#bt_multiple_deletion").off().on("click", function () {
    var files = [];
    var rows = $(".select").find("input[type=checkbox]:checked");

    rows.each(function () {
        files.push($(this).find(".filefolder-button").text());
    });
})
```

I really don't know what Im doing wrong. I tried to get the values with `.text()`, `.val()` etc.

My table row looks like this:

```
<tr class="select">
   <td>
       <span class="countEntries"><input id="lv_fifo_ctrl7_cb_delete_file" type="checkbox" name="lv_fifo$ctrl7$cb_delete_file" /></span>
   </td>
   <td>
       <img src="images/icons/013_document_02_rgb.png" alt="document" />
   </td>
   <td class="name">//the button i want to get the value from
       <input type="submit" name="lv_fifo$ctrl7$bt_file" value="013_document_png.zip" id="lv_fifo_ctrl7_bt_file" class="filefolder-button download file del" style="vertical-align: central" />
   </td>
   <td>
       <span id="lv_fifo_ctrl7_lb_length">33.14 KB</span>
   </td>
   <td>
       <span id="lv_fifo_ctrl7_lb_CreationTime">21.10.2014 07:34:46</span>
   </td>
   <td></td>
   <td>
       <input type="submit" name="lv_fifo$ctrl7$bt_del_file" value="delete" id="lv_fifo_ctrl7_bt_del_file" class="delete-button delete-file" />
   </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `rows` is the `input` elements not the `tr` elements so in the loop you need to find the `tr` which contains the `input` then find the target element inside it

```
$("#bt_multiple_deletion").off().on("click", function () {
    var checked = $(".select").find("input[type=checkbox]:checked");

    var files = checked.map(function () {
        return $(this).closest('tr').find(".filefolder-button").val();
    }).get();
})
```

---

Another option is

```
$("#bt_multiple_deletion").off().on("click", function () {
    var rows = $(".select").find("tr").has('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
    //var rows = $(".select").find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').closest('tr');

    var files = rows.map(function () {
        return $(this).find(".filefolder-button").val();
    }).get();
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I saw my mistake there but it is somehow still not working. The array is still filled with empty entries.
When I alert the "files" array i get something like that ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"

Comment: @TimoJokinen can you share the html sample

Comment: i edited my question and added a sample of my tablerows. There are rows for files and rows for directories but the structure is the same.

Comment: @TimoJokinen you need to use `.val()` instead of `.text()` since int is an input element

Answer (score 0):

@Timo Jokinen Do you need this

```js
$("#bt_multiple_deletion").on("click", function () {
    
    var files = [];
    var rows = $(".select").find("input[type=checkbox]:checked");

    rows.each(function () {
        files.push($(this).parents("tr").find("td.filefolder-button").text());
    });
    console.log(files);
})
```

```html
<table class="select">
    <tr>
        <td class="filefolder-button">test1</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="filefolder-button">test2</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="filefolder-button">test3</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button id="bt_multiple_deletion">delete</button>
```

Checkout example link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chanchal_chandanbatwe/wezew7h2/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you got me wrong. I'm programming a filebrowser for my company and each tablerow is an entry and stands for either a file or a directory. I have a button with the filename/directory name, a checkbox and some other buttons for deleting, renaming etc.

Comment: i tried your code snippet and im still facing the problem that the array is filled with empty entries.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort, the problem is solved. :)